# Changing a href value by combobox select

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a combo box on a jsp page. And i have few anchor tags with href. I want to modify the href by updating href value based on combo box selected value. How to approach this?

Jsp Page is below with sortselect combobox and hres of prevLink, nextLink, numLink have to be modified.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <%@ include file="headerinclude.jsp"%>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="./newStudentPage.do"/>">New
                        Student</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="./updateInputForm.do"/>">Update
                        Student</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="./deleteInputForm.do"/>">Delete
                        Student</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <c:out value="List of active Students" />
    </h3>
    <div id="body">
        <label for="sortselect">SortBy</label> <select name="sortselect">
            <option value="firstname" selected>FirstName</option>
            <option value="lastname">LastName</option>
            <option value="gender">Gender</option>
            <option value="dob">DOB</option>
        </select>

        <table id="student-table" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>MobilNumber</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Courses</th>
            <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${student.firstName}</td>
                    <td>${student.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${student.gender}</td>
                    <td>${student.DOB}</td>
                    <td>${student.email}</td>
                    <td>${student.mobileNumber}</td>
                    <td>${student.address}</td>
                    <td><c:forEach var="course" items="${student.courses}">
                    ${course}&nbsp;
                </c:forEach></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>

        <%--For displaying Previous link except for the 1st page --%>
        <c:if test="${currentPage != 0}">
            <td><a id="prevLink"
                href="./getHomePage.do?first=${currentPage - maxPageRecords}&max=${maxPageRecords}&sortBy=firstname&sortDirection=asc">Previous</a></td>
        </c:if>

        <%--For displaying Page numbers. 
    The when condition does not display a link for the current page--%>
        <table id="page-table" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <c:forEach begin="1" end="${noOfPages}" var="i">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${currentPage eq ((i-1) * maxPageRecords)}">
                            <td>${i}</td>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <td><a id="numLink"
                                href="./getHomePage.do?first=${(i-1) * maxPageRecords}&max=${maxPageRecords}&sortBy=firstname&sortDirection=asc">${i}</a></td>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <%--For displaying Next link --%>
        <c:if test="${currentPage lt ((noOfPages - 1) * maxPageRecords)}">
            <td><a id="nextLink"
                href="./getHomePage.do?first=${currentPage + maxPageRecords}&max=${maxPageRecords}&sortBy=firstname&sortDirection=asc">Next</a></td>
        </c:if>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <%@ include file="footerinclude.jsp"%>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Considering the values of `<option>` tag to be `Links`, I will go with following approach:**

Create an `id` attribute for your `<a>` tags so that they can be selected via `JavaScript`.

```
<a id="link-id" href="#previous-address"> This link's href will change </a>

<select onchange=" 
        document.getElementById('link-id').setAttribute('href', this.value);
        document.getElementById('link-id').innerHTML = this.value;" >
    <option value="#previous-address">Select</option>
    <option value="www.google.com">google</option>
    <option value="www.facebook.com">facebook</option>
    <option value="www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</option>
</select>
```

For testing purpose, i added `document.getElementById('link-id').innerHTML = this.value;` to `onchange` method too, but you don't need it.

If you need to change `href` of multiple `<a>` tags with/without respect to the value selected in `<select>` tag, make a `JavaScript` function and in `onchange` method, call that `JavaScript` function by passing the value selected in `<select>` tag.